# How to delete the ORDERS in salesforce CPQ?

Tags: cpq, quote, order, contracts

I created ORDERS for a quote and now I need them to be gone from (deleted). The quote is the PRIMARY Quote of the opportunity and it's the only quote we have on the Opportunity.

When I'm trying to delete the ORDERS on the quote, at first I can't see the DELETE button and I am getting this error.
[image]

I have the ORDER PRODUCT records on the orders and which I have deactivated manually. Also, the CONTRACTS which were created on the ORDER, I have deleted them.

I am not able to figure out, how to delete the ORDER records? Any help is appriciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the solution to this, we need to remove the Quote value from the Order record.

[image]

Then we can deactivate the ORDER and then delete the record.

Thanks

Comment: This issue arrived when I was working on the Billing Specialist superbadge. If it is the same for you, there is another workaround for this, you need to Disable the Triggers from the managed packages installed in your org. For the superbadge they are Salesforce Billing and Salesforce CPQ. 
After disabling the triggers delete the required object's record and then activate the triggers again.